# Why I do not receive after_key from my composite aggregation query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Elastic search Version: 6.2.4.
My query

```
"aggs": {
        "composite_agg": {
          "aggs": {
            "ActDate": {
              "max": {
                "field": "details.details.ActDate",
                "format": "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSSSSSSZZ"
              }
            }
          },
          "composite": {
            "size": 2,
            "sources": [
              {
                "OrgId": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "details.details.OrgId"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

The result of the query

```
 "aggregations": {
        "composite_agg": {
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": {
                "OrgId": 16777217
              },
              "doc_count": 40,
              "ActDate": {
                "value": 1554408754291,
                "value_as_string": "2019-04-04T20:12:34.2910000+00:00"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "OrgId": 16777218
              },
              "doc_count": 1,
              "ActDate": {
                "value": 1554402199081,
                "value_as_string": "2019-04-04T18:23:19.0810000+00:00"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Why I do not receive after_key to get more items.
There are more items than I got in my query and this I see if I increase the size parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality will work on 6.3.* or later version. Please check 6.2.* manual https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0):

The `after_key` parameter was added to composite aggregation response [since version 6.3.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/28358) of Elasticsearch. In version 6.2.x for the same purpose you can use the `key` parameter from the last composite bucket returned by the query, see [explanation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_after) in official documentation.